# How to create a javascript function using Scala.js?

Tags: javascript, scala, d3.js, scala.js

I've created a ScalaJS project using:

http://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial.html

Reading the docs at http://www.scala-js.org/doc/faq.html, it does not seem that creating and calling a JavaScript function is described?

How do I create a JavaScript function and invoke it?

I'll manually add d3 to the head element to index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

But how do I create the below code using ScalaJS?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1200)
            .attr("height", 1200)
            .attr("text-align", "center");

    testFunction(svgContainer);
});

<script>
 function testFunction(svgContainer) {
    alert(svgContainer)
}
</script>
```

Entire index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example Scala.js application</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Example Scala.js application - full-optimized version</h1>

<p>After having compiled and full-optimized properly the code for the application
(using `sbt fullOptJS`), you should see "It works" herebelow.
See README.md for detailed explanations.</p>

<div id="playground">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./target/scala-2.10/my-project-fastopt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./target/scala-2.10/my-project-launcher.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Update:

```scala
object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp {
  def main(): Unit = {

    jQuery(dom.document).ready { () => {

        val svgContainer = "d3.select(\"body\").append(\"svg\").attr(\"width\", 1200).attr(\"height\", 1200).attr(\"text-align\", \"center\")";
        val function = "callFunction(svgContainer)";
      }
    }
  }

  def callFunction(svgContainer): Unit = {

  }
}
```

In `callFunction` should svgContainer be typed, will `callFunction` be created as a JavaScript function when built using `fastOptJS`?

Within `jQuery(dom.document).ready {`, is this the correct method of creating `svgContainer` and `testFunction`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala.js, `scala.FunctionN`s can be converted implicitly to `js.FunctionN`s and back, so you basically don't need to do anything: just pass in a lambda to the JavaScript call. There is an example of this [in Step 5 of the the tutorial](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial.html#using-jquery), under "Setup UI in Scala.js". For your code, it would look like this:

```
jQuery(dom.document).ready { () =>
  val svgContainer = ...
}
```

You can find more information on this in the [calling JavaScript guide](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html).

**Update:**

Here is the translation of your entire JavaScript snippet:

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import org.scalajs.dom           // see https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom
import org.scalajs.jquery.jQuery // see https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-jquery

object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp {
  val d3 = js.Dynamic.global.d3 // assuming you don't have static types for d3, here

  def main(): Unit = {
    jQuery(dom.document).ready { () =>
      val svgContainer =
        d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", 1200)
          .attr("height", 1200)
          .attr("text-align", "center")
      testFunction(svgContainer)
    }
  }

  def testFunction(svgContainer: js.Dynamic): Unit = {
    dom.alert(svgContainer.toString())
  }
}
```

As you can see:

1. For libraries that have static types for Scala.js (e.g., DOM and jQuery), it is best to use these static types. Here is use `ready()`, `dom.document` and `dom.alert` in a statically typed fashion.
2. When you don't have static types, you can use `js.Dynamic` to manipulate JavaScript values in a dynamically typed way, using the normal syntax (not strings)
3. You define functions with `def`. It shouldn't matter to you whether they are compiled as JavaScript functions or not: just write your Scala code without thinking about it, the compiler will do its job.

Comment: please see question update, I'm unsure how to pass the svgContainer parameter to function and invoke same function?